# mysql select records greater than 3 months

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I am trying to write a query to select all records from `users` table where `User_DateCreated` (datetime field) is >= 3 months from today.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    users
WHERE   user_datecreated >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

Comment: if unix timestamp needed: ```WHERE user_datecreated <= unix_timestamp(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)```

Comment: isn't it user_datecreated <= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH ?

Comment: @user2821242: it says `>=` in the question

Comment: question as it stands, makes no sense. Maybe the author wanted data of the last 3 months (answer given), or data of everything up until 3 months ago (answer of user2821242).... but asking for all data from now until 3 months from now is an interesting exercise in time travel, or time zones on Venus :)

Comment: @juliuspatta: shouldn't it be a comment on the question?

Answer (score 16):

If you want to ignore the time of day when a user was created you can use the following. So this will show someone created at 8:00am if you run Quassnoi's example query at 2:00pm.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    users
WHERE   DATE(user_datecreated) >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 6):

Using DATE(user_datecreated) prevents mysql from using any indexes on the column, making the query really slow when the table grows.

You don't have to ignore the time when the user was created if you remove the time from the "3 months ago" date, as all the users created that day will match the condition.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    users
WHERE   user_datecreated >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
```